# Company bank statement for a German business visa

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, india

I am working for a German company remotely, employed through a third party in India. For a short business visa to Germany, I think the embassy requires the company's bank statement, but my Indian company is not interested in sharing it. Is there a way I can skip the company's bank statement and just show mine? Will that work?

Comment: Why is your employer not willing to give you the adequate documentation to get a visa if they want you do go on a business trip to Germany? It would seem rather obvious, that they will have to assist you in this case.

Comment: Are you self-employed or employed by an agent company? Company bank statement should only be required if you are self-employed, in which case you would provide the bank statement of your *own* company. Of course any other company would not want to share its financial information with anyone else.

Comment: Ask about "i think embassy required company bank statement". I think it is not true, but as you see above, if you are travelling for you own company (which it is not the case). You may need a statement that company will pay you travel, food, accommodation (from India or from German company, depending who pay you).

Comment: Because Indian company is middleware and they are concerned about their financial statement privacy I am employed by an Indian company full time but this trip is sponsored by a German company so in this case, do I need a company bank statement which one?

Comment: The purpose of providing bank statements is to demonstrate financial capacity. So IMHO *if* you need bank statements from a company it will be from the one paying for your trip. If they’re not sponsoring you financially, then you don’t need them.